# Enabling WebP Support in GD Library on Ubuntu 18.04 running on LiteSpeed

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean, webp

We have GD Library installed on DigitalOcean's Litespeed server, however, it does not support WebP. I'd like to enable WebP support.

Answer (score 0):

This is on LiteSpeed' Engineer's to-do list but there is no ETA.

I know it doesn't sound like an answer, but you can either just wait for it or build it yourself.